# Class Cast Exception when trying to unmarshall xml JAVA

Tags: java, maven, xsd, jaxb

Trying to get past a class cast here:

Code:

```
final JAXBContext securityContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Securities.class);
final Securities securities = (Securities) securityContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(sourceMessage.getPayload())));
```

Error:

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement cannot be cast to com.model.Securities
```

Not sure what im doing incorrect,
any suggestion would be great.

thanks

Comment: How is this related to (the tagged) Maven?

Answer (score 0):

[`unmarshaller.unmarshal(source)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshal-javax.xml.transform.Source-) returns an `Object` reference. The actual type of the referenced object apparently is [`javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBElement.html). `com.model.Securities` (where does this come from?) isn't in the inheritance hierarchy of [JAXBElement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBElement.html) (in fact, there's just `Object` as only superclass; and it is a [generic type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) in addition) so there's no other choice than to throw a [ClassCastException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassCastException.html):

> Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance.